# Facebook C# SDK Can never get IsAthorized() to return true

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have been trying like heck to get this to work.  I am pretty confident that I have my Facebook app setup correctly and that I am using the correct appId and appSecret. When I debug the Login.aspx and put a breakpoint on the

```
if (response.session)
```

I see that it is filled out properly with the access_token. But when it hits the codebehind the

```
if (auth.IsAuthorized())
```

is always false!  Here is the code on the aspx page which is just from the sample.

```
<h2>Log In </h2>
    <p>
        <fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,offline_access,status_update,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
    </p>
    <div id="fb-root">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        FB.init({ appId: '<%: Facebook.FacebookContext.Current.AppId %>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function (response) {
            if (response.session) {
                // A user has logged in, and a new cookie has been saved
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                // The user has logged out, and the cookie has been cleared

                //src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I even tried using this in the codebehind of the login page

```
public FacebookSession CurrentSession
        {
            get { return (new CanvasAuthorizer()).Session; }
        }
 if (CurrentSession != null)
            {
                Facebook.FacebookClient fbApp = new FacebookClient(CurrentSession.AccessToken);
                dynamic result = fbApp.Get("/me");
            }
```

And CurrentSession is always null as well.

I have been racking my brains on this and googleing like heck.  And, again, I feel I have the FB app set up properly.  Oh, I am using the latest download, 5.0.03 beta.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing your application from the domain you registered your FB app with?  If not, then that might be your problem - I'm pretty sure that you need to be on the registered domain in order for the authorization to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

@HOCA  I am testing this thru my http://localhost:5000 which is how I have it set up in Facebook.  Again, when I set a breakpoint on the

```
if (response.session)
```

on the login.aspx page (not the codebehind) I am getting a fully populated session object with all the goodies in there.  It is just when it hits the codebehind that nothing ever gets "authorized".  And I have used this Facebook app very successfully with other Facebook asp.net code but I cannot ever get this SDK code to work.

Comment: I'm not sure is this makes any difference, but this is what's working for me:I'm on the server side I'm using 'Authorizer' instead of 'CanvasAuthorizer' and .